# Stack based iterative approach not finding ALL paths from one node to another

Tags: c#, graph, stack

I have a graph as follows:

```
"1", "3"
"1", "2"
"2", "1"
"3", "1"
"2", "3"
```

It is stored in a `dictionary<string, list<string>> adjList` as:

```
<
1, [3,2],
2, [1,3],
3, [1]
>
```

I have a `HashSet<string> verts` that stores all vertices as: `[1,2,3]`

I have a graph class as follows:

```
public class GraphStack
    {
        // adjacency list
        private Dictionary<string, HashSet<string>> adjList;

        // Constructor
        public GraphStack()
        {
            initAdjList();
        }
        public Dictionary<string, List<string>> flow = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

        private void initAdjList()
        {
            adjList = new Dictionary<string, HashSet<string>>();
        }

        public void addEdge(string u, string v)
        {
            if (!adjList.ContainsKey(u))
            {
                adjList.Add(u, new HashSet<string>());
            }
            if (!adjList[u].Contains(v))
            {
                adjList[u].Add(v);
            }
        }

        public Dictionary<string, List<string>> printAllPaths(string startNode)
        {
            HashSet<string> visited = new HashSet<string>();

            Stack<Tuple<string, List<string>>> stack = new Stack<Tuple<string, List<string>>>();
            stack.Push(Tuple.Create(startNode, new List<string> { startNode }));

            while (stack.Count > 0)
            {
                var currentNode = stack.Pop();
                string u = currentNode.Item1;
                List<string> currentPath = currentNode.Item2;

                if (visited.Contains(u))
                {
                    continue; // Skip already visited nodes
                }

                visited.Add(u);

                if (adjList.ContainsKey(u))
                {
                    foreach (string v in adjList[u])
                    {
                        if (!currentPath.Contains(v))
                        {
                            List<string> newPath = new List<string>(currentPath);
                           
                            newPath.Add(v);
                            stack.Push(Tuple.Create(v, newPath));

                            string first = newPath[0];
                            string last = newPath[newPath.Count - 1];
                            string currentFlow = string.Join("=>", newPath);
                            if (currentFlow.Contains("=>"))
                            {
                                string key = first + "|" + last;
                                if (flow.ContainsKey(key))
                                {
                                    flow[key].Add(currentFlow);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    flow.Add(key, new List<string> { currentFlow });
                                }
                            }
                            if (adjList.ContainsKey(last) && adjList[last].Contains(first))
                            {
                                newPath.Add(first);
                                string currentCycleFlow = string.Join("=>", newPath);
                                string cycleKey = first + "|" + first;
                                if (flow.ContainsKey(cycleKey))
                                {
                                    flow[cycleKey].Add(currentCycleFlow);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    flow.Add(cycleKey, new List<string> { currentCycleFlow });
                                }

                                newPath.RemoveAt(newPath.Count - 1); // Remove the added node
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return flow;
        }
```

The `printAllPaths` method takes the vertices as a parameter one by one in a for loop and tries to find all possible paths from 1 vertice to another, including if there is a cyclic path.

The output I receive should look like:

```
      1   1   1=>3=>1|1=>2=>1|1=>2=>3=>1
      1   3   1=>3|1=>2=>3
      1   2   1=>2
      3   1   3=>1
      3   3   3=>1=>3|3=>1=>2=>3
      3   2   3=>1=>2
      2   1   2=>1|2=>3=>1
      2   3   2=>1=>3|2=>3
      2   2   2=>1=>2|2=>3=>1=>2
```

But the output looks like:

```
  1   1   1=>3=>1|1=>2=>1|1=>2=>3=>1
  1   3   1=>3|1=>2=>3
  1   2   1=>2
  3   1   3=>1
  3   3   3=>1=>3|3=>1=>2=>3
  3   2   3=>1=>2
  2   1   2=>1|2=>3=>1
  2   3   2=>3
  2   2   2=>1=>2|2=>3=>1=>2
```

As you can see, from 2 to 3, it's missing the path: `2=>1=>3`

What am I doing wrong?